# How to look for text but exclude it from match regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a string `key word word` and I want to match the first `word` based on the fact that it's placed right after `key`.

I was trying this regex `/(?:key\s)word/g` and thought that non-capturing groups won't show up in the match. But the regex matches `key word` (using `string.match()`) which is not the desired outcome.

How can I write a regex **in JavaScript** where it looks for `key` behind `word` but excludes `key` from the match?

(**additional question**: what is the exact difference between non-capturing groups `(?:)` and capturing groups `()` ?)

Comment: use capturing group instead:- `(?:key\s)(word)`

Comment: That doesn't help since the output is the same as `(?:key\s)word`

Comment: you have to access the first capturing group as shown by @Avinash in his answer

Comment: Are there any other ways of doing it? Or is that it?

Comment: you can mimick the lookbehind in JS..google search :- _lookbehind alternative in JS_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exec` function which returns an array in which the first element denotes the whole match where the second element points to the chars captured by the first capturing group.

```
> var s = 'key word word'
> /\bkey\s+(\w+)/.exec(s)
[ 'key word', 'word', index: 0, input: 'key word word' ]
> /\bkey\s+(\w+)/.exec(s)[1]
'word'
> /\bkey\s+(word)/.exec(s)[1]
'word'
```

Comment: That's a good alternative, but are there any native ways of doing it? Something like `?<=` in PHP...